# Defining Arrays in Prototype Classes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, prototypejs

I was trying to create a prototype object with four attributes:
'name', 'basis' and 'rows', which are values taken from a form and
'head' which should be an array of string values.

Classdef:

```
var TableTemplate = Class.create();  
 TableTemplate.prototype = {  
    initialize: function(name, basis, head, rows) {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.basis = basis;  
        this.head = head;    
        this.rows = rows;  
   },  
};
```

It should be passed to a .php file in the backend as following:

```
function sendRequest() {  
 var sorting = doSorting();  
 //alert(sorting.inspect());  
 var table = new TableTemplate($F('templateName'), $F('basisTemplate'), sorting , $F('maxRows'));  
 new Ajax.Request("test.php",   
  {   
  method: 'post',   
  postBody: 'table='+ Object.toJSON(table),  
  onComplete: showResponse   
  });  
}
```

where 'doSorting()' returns a stringarray.

Problem:
I can't seem to get other attributes than the head (array) in the object, or this one kinda overwrites the others... When I try to get a name or basis, the array will be returned.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this? 
Thanks in advance for your help,

Mara

Comment: (OT) Your class definition there is for Prototype 1.5.x. If you're using 1.6.x (and ideally you should be, it's been a couple of years and a lot of bugfixes since 1.5), you'll want to update it so you're not replacing the prototype of the function returned by `Class.create`. More here: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Caveat: I'm not a PHP person, and it has some built-in JSON handling that I'm not familiar with. But I'm fairly familiar with Prototype.)*

You're specifying the `postBody` of the request, which means you're in charge of making sure it's correctly encoded. What you're sending will look something like this:

```
table={"name": "some template", "basis": "some head", "head": ["blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"], "rows": 15}
```

Depending on the contents, it may not be encoded as you're expecting at the other end.

Rather than specifyihng the `postBody`, I'd probably just send it as a parameter and let the framework worry about escaping things for me:

```
new Ajax.Request("test.php",   
  {   
  method: 'post',   
  parameters: {table: Object.toJSON(table)},  
  onComplete: showResponse   
  });
```

Then retrieve the JSON string from the "table" parameter on the PHP side and decode it.

If you're still not getting the result you expect, take a look at the JSON string and make sure you're getting what you're expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
I think the problem is solved now.